# Export UIDocument with custom file package UTI

Tags: ios, icloud, uidocument, uti, nsfilewrapper

I'm trying to export my `UIDocument` subclass with a `UIDocumentPickerViewController`. The subclass writes data to a `FileWrapper` and its UTI conforms to `com.apple.package`.

But the presented document picker shows *"Documents in iCloud Drive are not available because the iCloud Drive setting is disabled."*

[image]

The document is successfully written to the cache, as I can see from the exported container package.

[image: Cache directory]

When I change the document subclass and custom UTI to conform to a single file (e.g. `public.plain-text`), the document picker works fine and I can export the file. So the problem seems to be with the Document Type or Exported UTI.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

---

*Info.plist*

[image: Document Type and Exported UTI]

```xml
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Custom Doc</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.zxzxlch.documentsandbox.customdoc</string>
        </array>
        <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</array>

...

<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.apple.package</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Custom Doc File</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.zxzxlch.documentsandbox.customdoc</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>zzz</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

*CustomDocument.swift*

```
private let textFilename = "contents.txt"

class CustomDocument: UIDocument {
    var content = "Test"

    override func load(fromContents contents: Any, ofType typeName: String?) throws {
        guard let topFileWrapper = contents as? FileWrapper,
            let textData = topFileWrapper.fileWrappers?[textFilename]?.regularFileContents else {
                return
        }
        content = String(data: textData, encoding: .utf8)!
    }

    override func contents(forType typeName: String) throws -> Any {
        let textFileWrapper = FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: content.data(using: .utf8)!)
        textFileWrapper.preferredFilename = textFilename

        return FileWrapper(directoryWithFileWrappers: [textFilename: textFileWrapper])
    }

}
```

*ViewController.swift*

```
func exportDocument() {
    // Write to cache
    let cachesDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.cachesDirectory, in: .allDomainsMask).first!
    let dataDir = cachesDir.appendingPathComponent("export", isDirectory: true)
    try! FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: dataDir, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

    let fileURL = dataDir.appendingPathComponent("cookie").appendingPathExtension("zzz")

    let archive = CustomDocument(fileURL: fileURL)
    archive.content = "Cookie cat"

    archive.save(to: archive.fileURL, for: .forCreating) { success in
        guard success else {
            let alertController = UIAlertController.notice(title: "Cannot export data", message: nil)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(url: archive.fileURL, in: .exportToService)
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solves my problem: make the UTI also conform to `public.composite-content`, i.e.

```xml
<key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
<array>
    <string>com.apple.package</string>
    <string>public.composite-content</string>
</array>
```

I'm not sure why though.